# What if 2 session layers generate the same source port?

Tags: tcpip, session

Is it possible for an application's session layer function to produce a source port which is already being used by another application for a current TCP connection? How are these kept unique? The only way I can think of is if windows has a central session layer universal to all applications whose functions they can call, or at least central source port management, is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP works at the **transport** layer; not session layer.

TCP is indeed handled by the operating system. Individual applications (whether they have a session layer or not) do not directly craft their own TCP packets. Applications only make requests to the OS to open a TCP socket, connect it to a remote address:port, and send/receive data over it. Nowadays this is almost universally done using [BSD Sockets API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#Client-server_example_using_TCP) or something that resembles it.

By default, the *local* port for TCP sockets is assigned by the OS randomly. Applications may *request* a specific local port (aka "bind" to it), but the OS may refuse the request if it would make the socket non-unique. The same applies for 'client' and 'server' applications equally.

The *remote* port doesn't need to be unique (so you can have many HTTP clients at once) – only the {localaddr, localport, remoteaddr, remoteport} tuple must be unique.

(But nte that even though TCP connections are identified by a 4-tuple, the OS might actually have stricter rules and refuse the bind request if the local port is already used by *any* connection, even if other parameters of that connection are different.)

---

---

---

Side note: There *is* actually a feature, called "[raw sockets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2)" and restricted to privileged applications only, that allows them to generate IP packets with any protocol ID and any headers they like.

So what happens if an application tries to generate its own TCP packets via raw sockets? The operating system won't prevent the packets from being sent. However, the application cannot prevent the OS from reacting to incoming responses, either.

For example, the application can send a handcrafted TCP SYN and receive a SYN/ACK – but the OS *also* receives the same TCP SYN/ACK, and because it belongs to an unknown connection, the OS will send a TCP RST terminating the handshake.